# how to fix this “Required arguments: dst_hostname dst_port local_port” closed

Tags: java

Here is my TestServer class and clientclass everytime I get Required arguments: dst_hostname dst_port local_port message. what can I do to fix this? which ip's should I write to hostname.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                 if (args.length != 3) 
                 {
                 System.out.println("Required arguments: dst_hostname dst_port local_port");
                 return;
             }
                 String hostname = args[0];
             int dst_port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
             int local_port = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

             RDT rdt = new RDT("localhost", 25566, 25566,3,3);
             RDT.setLossRate(0.2);
             byte[] buf = new byte[RDT.MSS];         
             System.out.println("\n\n ======>SERVER IS WAITING TO RECEIVE<========\n\n " );


             while (true) {
                 int size = rdt.receive(buf, RDT.MSS);
                // System.out.println("size is " + size);
                 for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
                         System.out.print(buf[i]);
                 System.out.println(" ");
                 System.out.flush();
             } 
        }
}
```

and here is my TestClient class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestClient {

        public TestClient() {

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                 if (args.length != 3) {
                 System.out.println("Required arguments: dst_hostname dst_port local_port");
                 return;
              }
                 String hostname = args[0]; //dnsnamelook up to get ip
                 int dst_port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                 int local_port = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

             RDT rdt = new RDT("localhost", 25566, 25566,3,3);
             RDT.setLossRate(0.3);

             byte[] buf = new byte[RDT.MSS];  //buffer set to MSS
             byte[] data = new byte[543]; //data

             System.out.println("\n\n ======>CLIENT IS SENDING DATA<========\n\n " );
             for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
                 data[i] = 0;
             rdt.send(data, data.length);

             for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
                 data[i] = 1;
             rdt.send(data, data.length);

             for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
                 data[i] = 2;
             rdt.send(data, data.length);

             for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
                 data[i] = 3;
             rdt.send(data, data.length);

             for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
                 data[i] = 4;
             rdt.send(data, data.length);


             System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + "\n\nCLIENT HAS SENT ALL DATA \n\n" );
             System.out.flush();

             rdt.receive(buf, RDT.MSS);
             rdt.close();
             System.out.println("Client is done " );
        }

}
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: RDT rdt = new RDT("localhost", 25566, 25566,3,3);
             RDT.setLossRate(0.3);